# BuildFire: sdk root directory

Tags: directory, sdk, root, buildfire

I’m completely new to app coding - so I was trying to get buildfire sdk to run, but it keeps telling me (in the cmd prompt - I’m using Windows) ‘please run this command in the SDKs root directory’. Where do I find the root directory?

More info if needed:

Tried to run buildfire sdk - following buildfire’s own steps (using their youtube video) but I get lost when trying to find buildfire’s root directory. Please see picture attached.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

SDKs root directory is initialized through the cli command `buildfire init`, after having your cli installed globally by running:

> npm install buildfire-cli -g

Go to your working directory and run

> buildfire init

A new directory named BuildFireSDK would be generated for you

> cd BuildFireSDK && buildfire run

You can find more detailed instructions [here](https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/how-to-test-your-plugin-locally) on Buildfire SDK docs